# fixed header on scroll addClass

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with fixed scroll in Jquery.
Here is my project: http://jsfiddle.net/gxr58q5w/

And code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if( $(window).scrollTop() >= $('#ct-menu').offset().top && !($('#ct-menu').hasClass('ct-menu-scroll'))){
    $('#ct-menu').addClass('ct-menu-scroll');
    } else {
    $('#ct-menu').removeClass('ct-menu-scroll');
    }
});
```

So, 'ct-menu-scroll' adding/remove on each "scroll". What can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change if else condition , this will work fine

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if( $(window).scrollTop() >= $('#ct-menu').offset().top){
        if(!$('#ct-menu').hasClass('ct-menu-scroll')){
            $('#ct-menu').addClass('ct-menu-scroll');
        }
    } else {
        $('#ct-menu').removeClass('ct-menu-scroll');
    }
});
```